# Checking the suffix of a string in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I downloaded this endsWith function -

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.match(suffix+"$") == suffix;
}
```

and am trying to use it to verify a form input with

```
function validator(form){
    var input = form.user.value;

    if(input.endsWith("vdr")) {
        if(input != ""){
            $('#userb').fadeOut("fast");
            $('#userk').fadeIn("fast");
        }
    }else{
        $('#userk').fadeOut("fast");
        $('#userb').fadeIn("fast");
    }
}
```

I am using jQuery to show a div. The problem is it doesn't do anything, and since it works without the check for the endsWith(), it is probably that function that is causing trouble. Why is this not working? Are there any alternatives to the endsWith that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array of matches.  Try something like this:

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.match(suffix+"$")[0] === suffix;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`.match` will return an array/undefined, depending on whether it matched. Simply convert it to a Boolean:

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return !!this.match(suffix+"$");
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KcvMZ/

Answer (score 2):

You're just testing for a condition, so `RegExp.test` is more applicable. So ...

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return RegExp(suffix+"$").test(this);
}
```

... should work.

Answer (score 2):

Regexp-based implementations are flawed because they don't take special characters into account:

```
  alert("100$".endsWith("$")) // surprise
```

Non-regexp code will be correct and maybe also faster:

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    var n = this.lastIndexOf(suffix);
    return n >= 0 && n == this.length - suffix.toString().length
}
```